# How do you turn off syntax highlighting for new vim windows without a filename or file type?

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

After I installed the 'artesanal' theme for vim and turned syntax highlighting on, every vim window has syntax highlighting including brand new empty windows [No Name], without a name or file type. I'm wondering if any of you know how to keep syntax highlighting on for every file with an extension but have it disabled for any file without a name or file extension.
[image: Example of syntax highlighting on no file extension]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should not happen. I don't know *artesanal* (and "theme" is an undefined term inside Vim; it has *colorschemes*, *filetype plugins*, and *syntax scripts*; I hope it's not a full Vim "distribution" like *spf-13* and *Janus*, which lure you with a quick install and out-of-the-box settings, but you pay the price with increased complexity (you need to understand both Vim's runtime loading scheme and the arbitrary conventions of the distribution) and inflexibility (the distribution may make some things easier, but other things very difficult)).

It looks like a syntax is active even for plain files. Usually, the syntax is determined by the *filetype*, so check `:verbose setlocal filetype?` first. If this returns a value, you need to look into the detection of [`:help filetypes`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/filetype.txt.html#filetypes).

If this is empty, it could also be that something sets `'syntax'` directly. You can check in the same way: `:verbose setlocal syntax?`.

Now, if that also is empty, and `:syntax list` doesn't show something, the highlighting could also come from `:match` or `:call matchadd()` commands; `:call clearmatches()` would remove this then. (And you still would need to find the source that defines those matches.)

Comment: ':verbose setlocal filetype?' got it fixed, there was something changing the file type to a javascript file which was why it was getting syntax highlighting.

Comment: Ah, great that you were able to figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if a filetype has been set

```
if &filetype != ""
  syntax enable
endif
```

Comment: I tried it but python and js files also trigger the if statement